# How get access_token from body for use in another method

Tags: scala, performance-testing, gatling, scala-gatling

Good afternoon. Slightly confused in the Gatling documentation, I can not find a solution. I want to get a token to use in another method as a header. Here is an example of the first method where I get a token:

```
  exec(
    http("HTTP Request auth")
      .post("http://blabla:9001/connect/token")
      .header("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
      .formParam("grant_type","password")
      .formParam("username", "${login}")
      .formParam("password", "${password}")
      .formParam("client_id","ro.client")
      .formParam("client_secret","secret")
      .check(status is 200)
      .check(header("access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
      .check(header("token_type").saveAs("token_type"))
  )
```

Here's the second method, where I want to pass the token:

```
  .exec(
    http("HTTP Request createCompany")
      .post("/Companies/CreateCompany")
      .header("Authorization","${token_type} + ${access_token}")
      .check(status is 200)
  )
```

As a result, writes that a token was not found:

```
Request:
HTTP Request auth: KO header(access_token).find(0).exists, found nothing
```

But then he writes:

```
body={"access_token":"7e8c1d997dd92f16a87fa7ffb8a88ab14eb05a8883d78fe8652d072f24b5ca4a","expires_in":31536000,"token_type":"Bearer"}
```

I guess I find it wrong here:

```
.check(header("access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
.check(header("token_type").saveAs("token_type"))
```

Comment: Can try to get the `session` and `session.getAttribute("access_token")`.? reference: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/gatling/qErj87jujGQ/e0S6IgTLsC8J

Answer (score 1):

The body of the first request is a Json payload, you need to use `jsonPath`, which is like XPath for Json:

```
.check(jsonPath("$.access_token").saveAs("access_token"))
.check(jsonPath("$.token_type").saveAs("token_type"))
```

Also, the header of the second request will print as:

```
.header("Authorization", "${token_type} + ${access_token}")
=> Authorization: Bearer + 7e8c1d997dd92f16a87fa7ffb8a88ab14eb05a8883d78fe8652d072f24b5ca4a
```

Unless you really want the extra `+`, the right header construction might be:

```
.header("Authorization", "${token_type} ${access_token}")
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to do like this ->

```
 exec { session => var access_token ='' ; 
                 your exec code

        session.setAll( "token_type" -> access_token );
        }
```

Then token_type is available to use.